# Bootstrap 4 - Modal Header with Tabs - How to Reduce Header Height

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I'm working in Bootstrap 4, and I have created a Modal Dialog with Tabs. The problem I'm having is the Modal Header with Tabs height, I need to reduce it.  Here's what it looks like now:

Header - Tall

[image]

Here's what I would like it to look like:

Header - Normal
[image]

Here's my Bootstrap Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#AAA" data-toggle="tab">
                                AAA
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#BBB" data-toggle="tab">
                                BBB
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#CCC" data-toggle="tab">
                                CCC
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my custom CSS, all other CSS is Default Bootstrap 4:

```
.modal-header {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabs-top {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border: 0;
}

.tabs-4 .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 25%;
    border: 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    border: 0;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    color: #ffd800;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    border: 0;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a.active {
    border: 0;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    color: #ffd800;
}

.nav-item {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: it seems like you have some padding set up for your anchor tags. Better to check your css or post the css here or some fiddle

Comment: @Arun - OK, Custom CSS added to Post

Comment: Can you put this in jsFiddle with all required css?

Comment: I'm new to this - what/where is JSFiddle?

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/aq9Laaew/236051/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reducing the padding of `.modal-header`

```
.modal-header {
  padding: 0;
}
```

By default, Bootstrap 4 sets it at 1rem (below, copied directly from the BS css file):

```
.modal-header {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}
```

Comment: That's definitely an improvement, but it's still about twice as tall as I want it to be, what else can be reduced?

Comment: Good to hear, but we would need to see all of your included CSS to figure out what is going on

Comment: I've updated the custom CSS in the original post above, under the sentence: "Here is my custom CSS, all other CSS is Default Bootstrap 4:", also in this JSFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/aq9Laaew/236051/. Aside from that I'm only using the OOTB Bootstrap v4.1.3 Bootstrap.css file.

Comment: You had lots of unnecessary spacing in your original code, I made another fork on your JSFiddle, found here: https://jsfiddle.net/w3xrktvp/. So basically, no other styling adjustments were needed, just had to clean and format your code to remove blank spaces.

Comment: Thanks for going to that trouble Edward.  I still need to reduce the header size to what's shown in my Header Normal image above - is there any other spot I can modify?